# Guice: @Nullable refuses to work with @Named

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, nullable

I'm attempting to create a `@Named Integer` parameter in Guice that allows null values for circumstances where no value is applicable:

```
@Singleton
public class MyClass extends SomeOtherClass {
    @Inject
    MyClass(Object o, @Named("the name") @Nullable Integer myParam) {
        ...etc...
    }
}
```

and

```
@Provides
@Named("the name")
public Integer getParamName() {
    // Set to null for Not Applicable
    return null;
}
```

Unfortunately, Guice doesn't seem to like this:

```
null returned by binding at my.package.ApplicationConfig$MyModule.getParamName()
 but parameter 1 of my.package.MyClass.<init>() is not @Nullable
```

The `@Nullable` annotation I'm using is `com.google.inject.internal.Nullable`, which is included in Guice and does have `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.

Similar questions I've found on Stack Overflow were unfortunately either nonconstructive or not applicable. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding @Nullable to provider method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `myParam` have to be an `Integer` (e.g. because it's overriding a method, etc)? If not, consider making it a non-nullable `Optional<Integer>`, which Guice should be able to handle. Your provider then returns either `Optional.of(someValue)` or `Optional.absent()`.

Comment: As the other suggestions don't seem to work for me for some reason, I'll give in to reason and simply abandon `null` in favor of your suggestion. :)

Comment: See also [`OptionalBinder`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.1/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/OptionalBinder.html).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @yshavit. It's usually not a good idea to have `null` represent state. But you should be able to get this to work. Try using `javax.annotation.Nullable` instead. You can find an implementation here:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```